# 'Category' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to programming
I have different categoriries in my django website, I created the model, view. but when I try to go to the localhost/category/categoryname, I get the error: "Category object is not iterable"
I appreciate your help in advance

```
#url.py
urlpatterns = [
path('', home, name='home'),
path('article/<slug:slug>', detail, name='detail'),
path('article', article, name='article'),
path('category/<slug:slug>', category, name='category')]
```

###############################################

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, Http404
from .models import Article, Category


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
context = {
    "articles": Article.objects.filter(status="Published")
}
return render(request, 'website/home.html', context)


def detail(request, slug):
context = {
    "article": get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug, status="Published")
}
return render(request, 'website/detail.html', context)


def article(request):
context = {
    "articles": Article.objects.filter(status="Published"),
    "category": Category.objects.filter(status=True)
}
return render(request, 'website/article.html', context)


def category(request, slug):
context = {
    "category": get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
}
return render(request, 'website/category.html', context)
```

###############################

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Category Topic")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name="Category Address")
status = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Do you want to show?")
position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="position")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Category"
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
    ordering = ['position']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Article(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Draft', 'Draft'),
    ('Published', 'Published')
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Category", related_name="articles")
description = models.TextField()
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-publish']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

######################

```
#category.html

{% for article in category.articles.all %}
        <article class="entry" data-aos="fade-up">

          <div class="entry-img">
            <img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url }}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>

          <h2 class="entry-title">
            {{ article.title }}
          </h2>

          <div class="entry-meta">
            <ul>
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="icofont-user"></i>
                  <a href="detail.html">John Doe</a></li>
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="icofont-wall-clock"></i>
                  <a href="detail.html"><time>{{ article.publish }}</time></a></li>
                <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="icofont-tags"></i>
                <ul class="tags">
                    {% for cat in article.category.all %}
                        <a href="#">{{ cat.title }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                  </li>
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="icofont-comment"></i>
                  <a href="detail.html">12 Comments</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="entry-content">
            {{ article.description|truncatewords:30}}
            <div class="read-more">
              <a href="{% url 'website:detail' article.slug %}">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </article><!-- End blog entry -->

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you post the full error log

Comment: TypeError at /category/water 'Category' object is not iterable

Comment: Show the rest of your `category.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

your code is shallow- please do this to retrieve category list

```
  def get_queryset(self):category =              
      get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))                                               
      return Post.objects.filter(category_id=category).order_by("-created")
```

you can use this to retieve category by specific list
`Article.objects.filter(post__category__contains='politics'),`

Comment: How does this answer OP's question. OP is not even using Class Based Views....

Answer (score 0):

I changed the view and the problem solved:

```
def category(request, slug):

cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
context = {
"category": cat.articles.all()
}
return render(request, 'website/category.html', context)
```